# Migrate to another version in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Im working on ruby on rails open source projects. So after cloning from github i setup the mentiones pg database in Gemfile by using command `rails db:create` successfully it created the database  . Now there are 809 migration files , to migrate with postgres database i ran the

```
rake db:migrate
```

Im getting the below error

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

  class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
D:/Freelance/pupilfirst/db/migrate/20131204110627_create_events.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
StandardError: Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

  class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
D:/Freelance/pupilfirst/db/migrate/20131204110627_create_events.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

there are 809 migrations files are there . so can anyone help me out from this. my rails version is ``rails 6.1.5.1`

Comment: You can either do what it says, or use a compatible version of Rails.

Comment: Do i mention rails version in all 809 files with [6.1] is it feasible way

Comment: But that’s the version you’re using, which doesn’t seem like it’d work—you’d want the version the migration was written for, like it says, or update the migrations. It could be as simple as search-and-replace(s) on all the migrations.

Comment: No i want to migrate the migrations with current rails version 6.1 which im using

Comment: … And the migrations were written for a previous version of Rails, which apparently uses a different migration base class. So you can update all the migrations. The message is literally telling you what the problem is—it’s not clear what options you think there are if you want to run an old Rails app on newer Rails other than to fix the app.

Comment: How can i fix it either i have to update all migration files or i have to roll back to rails 4.2

Comment: Yes; that’s what I’ve been saying.